# Error while installing MSI using Wine in ubuntu 16

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-installer, wine

I am trying to run my .Net service using wine. when i ran my msi using wine then while installing it throwing an error saying

> Error 1001 Installutilib.dll: Unknown Error

[image]

can anyone help me getting through this error and why might be this error is comming

Comment: Don't use this technology, but I suppose the .NET framework could be missing, or be the wrong version for the MSI being installed?

Comment: Are you sure the package is for 32 / 64 version (your env) ?